# Problem installing passenger with Nginx with rvm on linux

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, rvm

Tried to install Passenger with Nginx (on EC2 Linux). I'm using ec2-user (instead of Root). Ruby 1.9.2 with RVM.

Passenger gem installs correctly.

But when I try:

```
passenger-install-nginx-module
```

I get:

Checking for required software...

```
 * GNU C++ compiler... not found
 * The 'make' tool... found at /usr/bin/make
 * A download tool like 'wget' or 'curl'... found at /usr/bin/wget
 * Ruby development headers... found
 * OpenSSL support for Ruby... not found
 * RubyGems... found
 * Rake... found at /home/ec2-user/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.2-p180/rake
 * rack... found
 * Curl development headers with SSL support... not found
 * OpenSSL development headers... not found
 * Zlib development headers... not found
```

Although the above exist. for instance if I type:

```
$> gcc
$> gcc: no input files
```

Saw somewhere online that I can try using:

```
rvmsudo passenger-install-nginx-module
```

but I get a problem:

```
--------------------------------------------

Checking for required software...

 * GNU C++ compiler... not found
 * The 'make' tool... found at /usr/bin/make
 * A download tool like 'wget' or 'curl'... found at /usr/bin/wget
 * Ruby development headers... found
 * OpenSSL support for Ruby... not found
 * RubyGems... found
Unable to locate the RVM path. Your RVM installation is probably too old. Please update it with 'rvm update --head && rvm reload && rvm repair all'.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Tried to do what the message says? `rvm update --head && rvm reload && rvm repair all`

Comment: Install all the libraries that are not found.Also passenger writes how to install it after failing

Comment: @pablob yes I did. Indeed I just installed RVM so it's the latest

Comment: @fl00r they are installed (as a Root) but I'm running the Passenger installer as ec2-user (is that a problem?)

Comment: It shouldn't be since you're using `rvmsudo`.

Answer (score 4):

you have to do this:

```
rvm remove 1.9.2 
rvm pkg install openssl
rvm install 1.9.2 --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr
```

Comment: is now: rvm pkg install openssl

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that a compiler and all dependency libraries are present on the system before attempting to install Rubies and/or Passenger. You can obtain a list of recommended base dependencies for Ruby based applications by running the following command.

```
user$ rvm requirements
```

Install all dependencies listed for 'ruby' before attempting to install the interpreter?
The list varies by OS.

More information can be found on the RVM basics documentation page, https://rvm.io/rvm/basics/

~Wayne

Answer (score 0):

```
Unable to locate the RVM path.
```

That could be a symptom of not adding:

```
[[ -s "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

to your .bashrc (or profile or whatever). That can cause all kinds of weird problems.

Answer (score 0):

Am using **ruby-1.9.2-p180** with rvm.

 cd ~/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p180/ext/openssl/

 ruby extconf.rb 

 make

 make install

 passenger-install-gninx-module

Answer (score 0):

gcc is the wrong executable, Passenger is looking for g++ .  Install it with this:

```
sudo yum install gcc-c++
```

and passenger-install-nginx-module should stop complaining about gcc missing